# WooCommerce Ajax Cart Update Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I found a function to automatically update the cart when the quantity of an item is changed, and it was working until WooCommerce's 3.2.0 updated (latest update 3.2.1). I'm pretty sure something changed within this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_updated', 'wac_update');
function wac_update() {
    // is_wac_ajax: flag defined on wooajaxcart.js

    if ( !empty($_POST['is_wac_ajax'])) {
        $resp = array();
        $resp['update_label'] = __( 'Update Cart', 'woocommerce' );
        $resp['price'] = 0;

        // render the cart totals (cart-totals.php)
        ob_start();
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' );
        $resp['html'] = ob_get_clean();

        // calculate the item price
        if ( !empty($_POST['cart_item_key']) ) {
            $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
            $cart_item_key = $_POST['cart_item_key'];

            if ( array_key_exists($cart_item_key, $items)) {
                $cart_item = $items[$cart_item_key];
                $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $resp['price'] = $price;
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($resp);
        exit;
    }
}
```

My Javascript still working but here it is for a reference:

```
function refreshCart() {
    jQuery('.cart-builder .qty').on('change', function(){
        var form = jQuery(this).closest('form');

        // emulates button Update cart click
        jQuery("<input type='hidden' name='update_cart' id='update_cart' value='1'>").appendTo(form);

        // plugin flag
        jQuery("<input type='hidden' name='is_wac_ajax' id='is_wac_ajax' value='1'>").appendTo(form);

        var el_qty = jQuery(this);
        var matches = jQuery(this).attr('name').match(/cart\[(\w+)\]/);
        var cart_item_key = matches[1];
        form.append( jQuery("<input type='hidden' name='cart_item_key' id='cart_item_key'>").val(cart_item_key) );

        // get the form data before disable button...
        var formData = form.serialize();

        jQuery("input[name='update_cart']").val('Updating...').prop('disabled', true);

        jQuery.post( form.attr('action'), formData, function(resp) {
                // ajax response
                jQuery('.cart-collaterals').html(resp.html);

                el_qty.closest('.cart_item').find('.product-subtotal').html(resp.price);

                console.log(resp.test);

                jQuery('#update_cart').remove();
                jQuery('#is_wac_ajax').remove();
                jQuery('#cart_item_key').remove();

                jQuery("input[name='update_cart']").val(resp.update_label).prop('disabled', false);
            },
            'json'
        );
    });
}
```

I've been looking through the change log, https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt, but I can't find what would be conflicting now. Like I said, it was working perfectly before this updated.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: No errors, and I added each response to a console log and everything there is working property. It just seems the price isn't updating

Comment: This is on the cart page is that correct? I'm looking into it now...

Comment: That is correct

Comment: For the onChange function I had to change the selector from '.cart-builder .qty' to '.woocommerce-cart-form .qty'.  It fires the javascript but the price it is updating the total with is the price of one item and not the multiplied price.  The global get_cart() function only returns a qty of 1 for the cart item when I modify the quantity on the cart this is where the problem is.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @KeithPetrillo found any solution?

Comment: No I am still struggling. I'm positive it's because of the update though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a simpler solution, I am just appending a script to the bottom of the cart page but you could also enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_script` function which is the best way.  All it does it simulates the pressing of the update cart button.

```
function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $(function(){
                    $('div.woocommerce').on( 'change', '.qty', function(){
                        $("[name='update_cart']").trigger('click');
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );
```

Comment: I don't want to use this solution because the cart template being used isn't on the actual cart page but a widget. So doing it this way will trigger a refresh instead of ajax.